# GAS Library and WebApp Permissions [ReferenceError: "service" is not defined.]

Tags: javascript, oauth, google-apps-script, google-fusion-tables

**Background / Summary**

I have been using libraries extensively and I am now getting my permissions setup so I can distribute the app to some users for testing. Unfortunately, it's being very unpredictable. I've simplified the problem as follows:

I have a simple webApp that is making a simple API call to a fusion table. It calls a function in my Fusion Tables Library. The function in my Fusion Table Library also uses a function from my OAuth Library. This process has worked perfectly when executing from my primary gmail account (to which all resources belong). However, I am now setting up the permissions and it will not work from another account. When executing this webApp from another account, I get the following error (except under one scenario, described later):

> ReferenceError: "service" is not defined.

**Detail & Resources**

I am using Google's oAuthConfig class which defaults me to OAuth1.0.

Permissions are set as follows:

webApp

- Execute as: user accessing the webApp
- Who has access: anyone
- sharing: Anyone who has the link can view

Fusion Table Library

- Execute as: user accessing the webApp
- Who has access: anyone
- sharing: Anyone who has the link can view

OAuth Library

- Execute as: user accessing the webApp
- Who has access: anyone
- sharing: Anyone who has the link can view

[My OAuth Library Code](https://script.google.com/d/1TU-VKYWSv0cIjy_mqK5H4kPeAUjekBIMGpPPDLT-xIpdRf5R-g4lbToG/edit?usp=sharing)

OAuth Library Project Key: Mnt39sDQPQvSd3QGZFFLcznt7vnFOnL

[Fusion Table Library Code](https://script.google.com/d/1GDaNg4PoZIVDFarcM8MR6Wr-b2QVN1w50z0a-cM8VAPWD8vbSO32XN1U/edit?usp=sharing)

Fusion Table Library Project Key: MigHa1npbg9PnkaJ8jFENSyUlmcxk5wr2

The simplified webApp that reproduces error: [Published webApp](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbyZviat_33Nj-2LTSRMLl3yAFD9_2UtnQHttUk-A7lA_ucq_Xeo/exec) (code below)

```
var oAuthFields = {
  'clientId' : '{...}',
  'scope' : 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fusiontables',
  'fetchUrl' : 'https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v1/',
  'clientSecret' : '{...}',
  'fusionId' : '{...}',
  'service' : 'fusiontables',
  'queryUrl' : 'https://www.google.com/fusiontables/api/query'
};

function doGet() {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();

  var tempVar = FTL.fusionRequest('GET', 'SHOW TABLES', oAuthFields);
  Logger.log('Result: ' + tempVar);

  app.add(app.createLabel('Success'));
  return app;
}
```

**Exceptions**

Now to make matters more interesting, if I change the "sharing" settings of the OAuth Library from 'Anyone who has the link can view' to 'Anyone who has the link can edit', everything works perfectly. I obviously do not want universal editing rights to my library so I am stuck on why that happens, as well as what I need to do to fix it.

I am not completely clear on how the 'execute as' and 'sharing' settings are taken into account when using libraries. I am hoping to have the webApp accessible by anyone, executed as the user, and I will implement access restrictions programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

I have identified this as an error with update propagation in GAS libraries. I have submitted an issue [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=2640) to the [issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/list).