# Library with identifier QUnit is missing - G Suite for Education Account

Tags: google-apps-script, tdd, libraries, qunit

I have been trying to use QUnit to test my code but have been getting this error: "Library with identifier QUnit is missing (perhaps it was deleted, or maybe you don't have read access?)."

I am sure I have installed it correctly with the correct key.

My google account is a G Suite for Education Account that's been set up by my company, I have two different Education accounts with them. Both accounts are in different organisational units from each other. One of them can run QUnit with no issues but I need it to work on the account that is throwing the error.

I took the following steps too add QUnit to my project:

1. Went onto Libraries and entered the code "MxL38OxqIK-B73jyDTvCe-OBao7QLBR4j"
2. Selected version 4.
3. Published as a Web App and then selected "Test web app for your latest code" to view the results.
4. I am then presented with the error message on a new tab.

When I try these same steps on my Personal Google Account as well there seems to be no issues.

Below is my QUnit code, if you can see where I've went wrong or if there are any G Suite Settings that should be changed that you know of that would be a great help.

```
function doGet( e ) {
  QUnit.urlParams( e.parameter );
  
  QUnit.config({
    title: "Unit tests for my project" 
  });
  QUnit.load( tests );
  return QUnit.getHtml();
};


function tests() {
  addEqual();
  addNotEqual();
  multiplyEqual();
  multiplyNotEqual();
}


function addEqual() {
  test("Add number to number", function() {
    equal(addNumbers(), 5, 'It worked!');
  });
}

function addNotEqual() {
  test("Add number to number", function() {
    equal(addNumbers(), 8, 'It worked!');
  });
}

function multiplyEqual() {
  test("Multiply Number with a Number", function() {
    equal(multiply(), 6, 'It Worked!');
  });
}

function multiplyNotEqual() {
  test("Multiply Number with a Number", function() {
    notEqual(multiply(), 9, 'It Worked!');
  });
}
```

Comment: What does your manifest file look like?

Comment: What steps you follow to add the library? Have you published your web app? Are you usin the /exec or the /dev link?

Comment: @Diego My manifest file looks exactly similar to the project I have working on my personal Google Account.

Comment: @Rubén So I went into resources, entered the code "MxL38OxqIK-B73jyDTvCe-OBao7QLBR4j". I then selected version 4 and saved it. That's the procedure I used. And yes I published the WebApp and then select latest code to check the tests where I am given the error message. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: @StephenMcBride Have you changed the library default title?

Comment: @Rubén I didn't touch the Identifier and kept it as QUnit.

Comment: Are you using the default runtime or the old one? Following the steps mentioned in the question it throws to me "ReferenceError: test is not defined (line 21, file "Code")"

Comment: @Rubén My runtime version is V8.

Comment: Try Qunitgs2 ??

Comment: @TheMaster I have tried this also but I get shown  "Library with identifier QUnitGS2 is missing (perhaps it was deleted, or maybe you don't have read access?)" unfortunately.

Answer (score 5):

#### Summary:

So far, the easiest way to solve the issue is not to use the library feature at all, but directly copy paste files from  the library's source. Note that all `.gs` and `.html` files should be included as separate files in your project. Other ways to solve includes various versions of deleting the calling script project and re-adding each library in a new project.  On the library developer side, it includes saving a new version of the library.

#### Possible Cause(s):

- Probably random/unknown

  - [Library with identifier XXXXXXX is missing (perhaps it was deleted?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15894523/library-with-identifier-xxxxxxx-is-missing-perhaps-it-was-deleted)
- Sharing  libraries with "view only" permissions

  - [GAS Library and WebApp Permissions [ReferenceError: "service" is not defined.]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15867528/gas-library-and-webapp-permissions-referenceerror-service-is-not-defined/15989576#15989576)
- Deleting older version(s) of the calling script/Webapp

  - [Not able to deploy the Web App: "library with identifier is missing" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61927446/not-able-to-deploy-the-web-app-library-with-identifier-is-missing-error)
- Deleting older version of library

  - https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36757993#comment36
  - [Why can't I import a Library in Google Scripts editor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51848687/why-cant-i-import-a-library-in-google-scripts-editor)
  - [Can NOT authorize calling Script for new ScriptDb when Included Library remains from previously deleted ScriptDb.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23070086/can-not-authorize-calling-script-for-new-scriptdb-when-included-library-remains)
- Changing from dev to fixed version of library:

  - [You do not have access to library [xyz], used by your script, or it has been deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46985541/)
- Libraries out of sync?

  - [Library with identifier LabelServices is missing (perhaps it was deleted?) / Something went wrong. Please reload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28125665/library-with-identifier-labelservices-is-missing-perhaps-it-was-deleted-som)

#### Possible  Solution(s):

- Sure Fix: Copy paste all dependencies directly from library source and not depend on  buggy library feature at all

  - [OAuth2 for Apps Script: Google Apps Script callback is changed dynamically after login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63667400/oauth2-for-apps-script-google-apps-script-callback-is-changed-dynamically-after#comment112584830_63667400)
- Share script with Anyone

  - [OAuth2 for Apps Script: Google Apps Script callback is changed dynamically after login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63667400/oauth2-for-apps-script-google-apps-script-callback-is-changed-dynamically-after#comment112612015_63667445) @AmitAgarwal
- Library side: Create a new version; Calling script side: Remove and readd libraries one by one:

  - [Library with identifier LabelServices is missing (perhaps it was deleted?) / Something went wrong. Please reload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28125665/library-with-identifier-labelservices-is-missing-perhaps-it-was-deleted-som) @theworldismyoyster
- Copy calling script project and rename Library

  - https://stackoverflow.com/a/32939032/ @SoftwareTester
- In a bound script, Share sheet+script

  - https://stackoverflow.com/a/61484114/ @Beyonder
- Delete calling project and  create new project and readd libraries:

  - https://stackoverflow.com/a/51587824/ @BruceKozuma
- Copy both calling  script and called library and readd library references

  - https://stackoverflow.com/a/47026231 @Kwynn Buess
- Share  library with edit privileges:

  - [GAS Library and WebApp Permissions [ReferenceError: "service" is not defined.]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15867528/gas-library-and-webapp-permissions-referenceerror-service-is-not-defined/) @ScottS.

#### Currently Open Issue Trackers:

- https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36762678
- https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36762341
- https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36765407

#### Closed Trackers(for research):

- https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36757993
- https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36758687
- https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36760089

#### Related:

- [How to call an Apps Script library function in Google Sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63552423/how-to-call-an-apps-script-library-function-in-google-sheet)

Comment: This sounds like a helpful solution for now! Sorry but I am a novice with Google Scripts. How would I find the libraries source to get these files?

Comment: @StephenMcBride It's usually in github. Copy paste all the files there.

Comment: Hi I am very sorry for my late message, I am still unsure how to do this. I have found the github for Qunit: https://github.com/qunitjs/qunit.

But I am unsure what files I am to copy over. Is there be any chance you could walk me through this?

Comment: @StephenMcBride That's the main JavaScript module. You can't use that. Your library version is basically from [here](https://github.com/simula-innovation/qunit/tree/gas/gas).  Someone also created [qunit2](https://github.com/artofthesmart/QUnitGS2). You'll basically  need all .gs and .html files from any of those.

Answer (score 0):

I followed the steps provided on the question, using my G Suite for Business account and the default runtime (Chrome V8) but I got another error

> ReferenceError: test is not defined (line 21, file "Code")

After replacing `test(...)` by `QUnit.test(...)`.The web page was correctly displayed.

I don't think that your G Suite account administrator bloqued your account to access receive files from outside your organization because you are able to see the library title and versions. There should be something that you missed to include in the question. Try to create a new project from scratch following the steps included in the question.

Resources

- [Set Drive users' sharing permissions](https://support.google.com/a/answer/60781?hl=en)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I followed what you have said but still have the same issue. To correct myself I am using a G Suite Account for Education if that makes a difference.